# Відповідник до слова "цвіклі"

Tags: вживання-слів, діалектизми

Доброго дня!
На Галичині досить часто можна почути таку назву страви як "цвіклі"або "цвітлі". Однак, жодного з цих слів немає у СУМі, а на Вікіпедії пише, що це польська та західноукраїнська страва, але як я розумію назва у неї польська. Отже, чи є у цієї страви якась українська назва, не діалектизм і не полонізм, чи, можливо, вона зустрічається лише в областях західної України, а тому якоїсь загальної української назви немає?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хрін з буряком. Або буряк з хроном. Кому яка пропорція більше подобається.
Традиційно готується до Великодня. Споживається з м'ясними стравами.

[Франко О.Ф. "Практична кухня" .- Львів: Каменяр, 1992](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Franko_Olha/Praktychna_kukhnia_vyd_1992/). подає на 93-ій сторінці назву страви як "Бурячки". Слід завважити, що ця книжка є перевиданням від 1929 року. Хоча така назва часто зустрічається в рецептах.